# Python Script that uses private key when available or username password

Tags: python, paramiko

I have a python script that uses paramiko to get some files.  The script calls a yaml config file to obtain the credentials for each client.  I now have the need to use a private key for a new client (I can make that work by itself) but I'm unable to use the script with both key and username/password supplied.  How can I get the script to use the private key if it is supplied or the username/password to login to sftp?  Right now when running the script and there is nothing in the private key the script fails.

```
import paramiko, StringIO
import logging
import os
import yaml

try:
     cfg=yaml.load(open("config.yml"))["local"]
     paramiko.util.log_to_file('sftpin.log')
     sftp = paramiko.Transport(cfg["host"], cfg["port"])
     key_string = cfg["key"]
     not_really_a_file = StringIO.StringIO(key_string)
     private_key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key(not_really_a_file, 
        password=cfg["key_passwd"])
     sftp.connect(username=cfg["user"], password=cfg["pass"] 
        pkey=private_key)
     sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(sftp)
     print 'Connecting'
     files = sftp.listdir(cfg["remote_outbox"])
     print 'Listing Contents'
     print files
     print 'Getting Files'
     for f in files:
        sftp.get(cfg["remote_outbox"]+f, cfg["local_inbox"]+f)
    print 'Job Completed'
finally: 
    try: 
       sftp.close()
    except NameError:
    print 'SFTP is not defined'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Hey Danny try follow snippet. Note: key value from config.yml is a full path to RSA private key file (like: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa).

```
import paramiko
import StringIO
import yaml


try:
    cfg=yaml.load(open("config.yml"))["local"]
    paramiko.util.log_to_file('sftpin.log')
    sftp = paramiko.Transport(cfg["host"], cfg["port"])
    key_string = cfg["key"]

    private_key = None

    if key_string is not None:
        f = open(key_string, 'r')
        s = f.read()
        not_really_a_file = StringIO.StringIO(s)

        private_key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key(not_really_a_file,
                                                    password=cfg["key_passwd"])

    sftp.connect(username=cfg["user"],
                 password=cfg["pass"],
                 pkey=private_key)

    sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(sftp)

    print 'Connecting'
    files = sftp.listdir(cfg["remote_outbox"])
    print 'Listing Contents'
    print files
    print 'Getting Files'

    for f in files:
        remote = "%s%s" %(cfg["remote_outbox"], f)
        local = "%s%s" %(cfg["local_inbox"], f)

        try:
            sftp.get(remote, local)
        except IOError:
            print "Failed to copy %s" % remote

    print 'Job Completed'

finally:
    sftp.close()
```

Regards KG.